# Guacamole logs "Wrong number of arguments"

Tags: server, rdp

I've built and installed Guacamole 1.0.0 and Tomcat 8.
Make and install went fine so far. Tomcat and Guacamole are running.
However I fail to connect (tried SSH and RDP).

Syslog says:

```
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: Creating new client for protocol "ssh"
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: guacd[28616]: INFO:#011Creating new client for protocol "ssh"
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: guacd[28616]: INFO:#011Connection ID is "$431c40da-9530-49e8-9f1a-72122d2a5e46"
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: Connection ID is "$431c40da-9530-49e8-9f1a-72122d2a5e46"
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28654]: Wrong number of arguments
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: guacd[28654]: ERROR:#011Wrong number of arguments
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: guacd[28654]: ERROR:#011Unable to load client plugin
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28654]: Unable to load client plugin
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: guacd[28616]: INFO:#011Connection "$431c40da-9530-49e8-9f1a-72122d2a5e46" removed.
Apr 13 21:05:17 myserver guacd[28616]: Connection "$431c40da-9530-49e8-9f1a-72122d2a5e46" removed.
```

For the completeness sake my configure-output before `make && make install`:

```
------------------------------------------------
guacamole-server version 1.0.0
------------------------------------------------

   Library status:

     freerdp ............. yes
     pango ............... yes
     libavcodec .......... yes
     libavutil ........... yes
     libssh2 ............. yes
     libssl .............. yes
     libswscale .......... yes
     libtelnet ........... yes
     libVNCServer ........ yes
     libvorbis ........... yes
     libpulse ............ yes
     libwebp ............. yes
     wsock32 ............. no

   Protocol support:

      RDP ....... yes
      SSH ....... yes
      Telnet .... yes
      VNC ....... yes

   Services / tools:

      guacd ...... yes
      guacenc .... yes
      guaclog .... yes

   Init scripts: no
   Systemd units: /etc/systemd/system
```

I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-88-generic i686).
I tried the latest Guacamole 1.1.0 first having the same error.

Unfortunately Google didn't help very much with the error message "Wrong number of arguments".
Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guacamole developer Nick Couchman [told me](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-1027?focusedCommentId=17084019&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17084019):

> The most likely explanation for this is that you are using a mismatched version of Guacamole Client with Guacamole Server (e.g. guacamole-server 1.0.0 with guacamole-client 1.1.0). Prior to version 1.1.0 the versions needed to match up. Starting with version 1.1.0 there is some negotiation done between the two to better enable cross-version compatibility, thought it's still a good idea to keep them in sync.

So I double checked the server and client version, both being 1.0.0.

However, I have tried to `apt-get install guacamole` before what installed 0.9.9, but didn't seem to work. I purged it again, so I didn't think this might cause problems, but that purge didn't remove everything. Another `apt autoremove` removed further packages including:

```
libguac-client-rdp0:i386 (0.9.9-2build1) ...
libguac-client-ssh0:i386 (0.9.9-2build1) ...
libguac-client-vnc0:i386 (0.9.9-2build1) ...
libguac11:i386 (0.9.9-2build1) ...
```

I assume these led to a version conflict bringing the `Wrong number of arguments` error. After removing these packages Guacamole works fine.